# Switching frame automatically in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I am aware similar questions have been answered, but I have read them thoroughly and cannot find a solution for myself.

After the `BMR_method` is done, and either the if, elif, or else options has completed, I want it to automatically load a new class/frame: `work` . But I cannot figure out how to do this. I tried adding different variations of `self.show_frame(work)`, also tried adding parent/controller parameters to the function but it will either tell me I am missing positional arguments or that the show_frame method doesn't exist. Please help.

```
import tkinter as tk
from decimal import Decimal
import time

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

def gender():
    if var1.get() and var2.get():
        print('Please only tick one box')
        var1.set(0)
        var2.set(0)
    elif var1.get():
        print('Male')
        bmr_male()
    elif var2.get():
        print('Female')
        bmr_female()
    else:
        print('Please tick male or female')

class theog(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        controller = self
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand= True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, BMR, work):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise() 

class StartPage(tk.Frame):  
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", width = 60)
        label.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Begin!", 
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(BMR))
        button.pack()

class BMR(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="BMR Calculator", width = 20)
        label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='W')
        label_height = tk.Label(self, text="Height (CM)")
        label_height.grid(column=3, row=0, sticky='E')
        label_weight = tk.Label(self, text="Weight (KG)")
        label_weight.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky='E')        
        label_age = tk.Label(self, text="Age")
        label_age.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky='E')

        self.text_height = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
        self.text_height.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.text_weight = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
        self.text_weight.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='W')
        self.text_age = tk.Entry(self, width=20, bg="white")
        self.text_age.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='W')

        self.resultvar = tk.StringVar()
        self.result = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.resultvar)
        self.result.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.var1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.var1.set(None)
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Male", bg='white', value='male', variable=self.var1).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='S')
        tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Female", bg='white', value='female', variable=self.var1).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='S')
        tk.Button(self, text="Submit!", width=6, command=self.bmr_method).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')


    def bmr_method(self, Entry=None):
        if self.text_height.get() and self.text_weight.get() and self.text_age.get() and self.var1.get() == 'male':
            bh = float(self.text_height.get()) * 5.0033
            bw = float(self.text_weight.get()) * 13.7516
            ba = float(self.text_age.get()) * 6.7550
            bmr = float(66.4730 + bh + bw - ba)
            self.resultvar.set('Your BMR is: ' + str(bmr))

        elif self.text_height.get() and self.text_weight.get() and self.text_age.get() and self.var1.get() == 'female':
            bh = float(self.text_height.get()) * 1.8496
            bw = float(self.text_weight.get()) * 9.5634
            ba = float(self.text_age.get()) * 4.6756
            bmr = float(655.095 + bh + bw - ba).round(1)
            self.resultvar.set('Your BMR is:' + str(bmr) +'\n press continue to find out \n your maintenance calories')
        else:
            'Please ensure all information has been entered and click again'
            self.resultvar.set('Please ensure all \n information has been \n entered and click again')
        self.controller.show_frame(work) #I WANT TO OPEN THE CLASS BELOW AFTER THIS METHOD HAS FINISHED

class work(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        controller = self


root = theog()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your class needs accept and save a reference to the controller so that you can access it later:

```
class BMR(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        ...
```

Then, you simply need to call the controller method `show_frame`:

```
self.controller.switch_frame(work)
```

Comment: Saved a reference to controller where?

Comment: @Remitto: in each page's `__init__`. For an example,  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter

Comment: I am sorry to bother but I am really struggling. I don't know what type to reference the controller. I tried self=controller among other things but none of it makes a difference. When I use self.controller.show_frame(work) it tells me I am missing positional arguments. Is there anywhere I can send you full code?

Comment: I've added the full code, the code at the bottom is what needs fixing. Thank you in advance